# React not updating the render after setState

Tags: reactjs

This is really driving me in nuts. I wrote so many components and this is so basic, but probably there is something that I can't realize in this simple scenario. Basically my render is not being updated when I set the state.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import styles from './styles'
import {css} from 'aphrodite'

export class Switcher1 extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        selected: 0
    }
 }

setIndex(ndx) {
    console.log(ndx)
    this.setState = {selected: ndx}
}

render() {
    console.log('Rendering...')
    const sel = this.state.selected
    return (
        <div className={css(styles.container)}>
            {this.props.options.map((item, index) => {
                const isSelected = index === sel
                return <div key={index}
                            className={isSelected ? css(styles.active) : css(styles.notActive)}
                            onClick={() => this.setIndex(index)}>
                    <img className={css(styles.image)}
                         src={"/assets/images/" + item.icon + (isSelected ? '_blue.svg' : '_white.svg')}/>
                    &nbsp;{item.text} - {sel} - {index} - {isSelected.toString()}
                </div>
            })}
        </div>)
  }
}
```

Updated code...but it's still not works...

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import styles from './styles'
import {css} from 'aphrodite'

export class Switcher1 extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        selected: 0
    }
    this.setIndex = this.setIndex.bind(this)
}

setIndex(ndx) {
    console.log(this.state)
    this.setState = ({selected: ndx})
}

render() {
    console.log('Rendering...')
    const sel = this.state.selected
    return (
        <div className={css(styles.container)}>
            {this.props.options.map((item, index) => {
                const isSelected = index === sel
                return <div key={index}
                            className={isSelected ? css(styles.active) : css(styles.notActive)}
                            onClick={() => this.setIndex(index)}>
                    <img className={css(styles.image)}
                         src={"/assets/images/" + item.icon + (isSelected ? '_blue.svg' : '_white.svg')}/>
                    &nbsp;{item.text} - {sel} - {index} - {isSelected.toString()}
                </div>
            })}
        </div>)
   }
}


Any thoughts ?
```

Comment: still in the updated code, you have not used `setState` correctly. `this.setState = ({selected: ndx})` change to `this.setState({selected: ndx})`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) You forgot to bind this to your setIndex method : `setIndex=(ndx)=> {`

2) the setState is wrong, replace by : `this.setState({ selected: ndx });`

result :

```
setIndex = (ndx) => {
    console.log(ndx);
    this.setState({ selected: ndx });
}
```

Comment: this.setIndex.bind(this)(index) supposed to work also, right ?

Comment: use an arrow function or update your constructor with `this.setIndex = this.setIndex.bind(this);`

Answer (score 2):

You have:

```
this.setState = {selected: ndx}
```

This is not how you set state. Try this:

```
this.setState({ selected: ndx });
```

Also, as @benjamin mentioned, you should bing the `setIndex` function by using an arrow function:

`setIndex = () => { ... }`

or binding in your constructor:

`this.setIndex = this.setIndex.bind(this);`

You can read the docs on `setState` [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html).

Comment: Looks like this is one error...but looks like there is more errors. See the answer from @benjamin